# Transport Mathematic function into a program

Tags: javascript, math, quadratic-curve

I try to import a mathematic function into Javascript.
It's the following formula:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.000004x%5E2%2B0.004x

Example Values:

> f(0) = 0
>
> f(500) = 1
>
> f(1000) = 0

So that is my function:

```
function jumpCalc(x) {
    return (-0.004*(x^2)+4*x)/1000;
}
```

[The values are completely wrong.](https://jsfiddle.net/6zhtnm1h/)

Where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: x^2 does not mean x power 2 in javascript, it's the xor operator. There is not power operator in JS, so try changing this to x * x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^` isn't doing what you think it is. In JavaScript, `^` is the Bitwise XOR operator.

> #### `^` (Bitwise XOR)
>
> Performs the XOR operation on each pair of bits. a XOR b yields 1 if a and b are different.
> — [MDN's Bitwise XOR documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR)

Instead you need to use JavaScript's inbuilt `Math.pow()` function:

> #### `Math.pow()`
>
> The `Math.pow()` function returns the base to the exponent power, that is, base<sup>exponent</sup>.
> — [MDN's Math.pow() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

```
return (-0.004*(Math.pow(x, 2))+4*x)/1000;
```

[**Working JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6zhtnm1h/1/).

Comment: Or just `x*x` (in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Use Math.pow like this

```
function jumpCalc(x) {
    return (-0.004*(Math.pow(x,2))+4*x)/1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this formula further to

```
function getThatFunc(x){
    return x * (-0.004 * x + 4) / 1000;
}
```